# Double-language application problem with Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm currently developing a web application using Next.js which will support 2 languages: my mother language and English. Right now I'm thinking of the following approach:

1. Create a folder: /pages/en-us

```
pages/
|--(all app pages)
|--en-us/
   |--(all app pages like above)
```

2. Wrap the app with a LanguageContext, and use a middleware to detect visitor's country by their IP on load, and redirects to `/en-us` path if they're foreign visitor or current language is set to English.

   *For example, `/login` will be redirected to `/en-us/login`.*

I know that there're some multi-language frameworks like [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) but my web app is quite simple and only needs 2 languages, so it won't be necessary to use them.

Is my approach good? If not, please give me some advice and recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you integrating i18next. Otherwise, you have to face code duplications and you cannot adjust all changes in the language files.
The middleware approach is interesting, but actually a better way me be to see the language of the user with `Navigator.language`. The [Navigator.language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/language) read-only property returns a string representing the preferred language of the user, usually the language of the browser UI.

I hope I could help you. Good luck with your project!